# rails link_to(image_tag) how to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I got this one:

```
<%=link_to(image_tag("topmenubuttons/kunden_OFF.png",:mouseover => "topmenubuttons/kunden_OVER.png", :mouseon =>"topmenubuttons/kunden_ON.png", :title => "Kunden"), customers_path ) %>
```

if i do this: (appended "Customer" next to customers_path)

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("topmenubuttons/kunden_OFF.png" , :mouseover => "topmenubuttons/kunden_OVER.png", :mouseon => "topmenubuttons/kunden_ON.png", :title => "Kunden"), "Customer" ,customers_path ) %>
```

I get an error:

I could do this:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("topmenubuttons/kunden_OFF.png" , :mouseover => "topmenubuttons/kunden_OVER.png", :mouseon => "topmenubuttons/kunden_ON.png", :title => "Kunden"), +"Customer" ,customers_path ) %>
```

But there must be a better solution.

link_to "something", customer_path, something is the name of the link.

How can I pass the name of the link to rails in my example?

Thank you guys It works but it looks like this:
[image]

But I'd like the Customer on top, how can I do this?

Comment: `link_to` can accept [block](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) - maybe it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the `link_to` helper does is generate the opening and closing `<a>` tags. The first argument (in your case the `image_tag`) is what goes in between the tags (this would be the name of the link). So you'd get:

```
<a href="/customers">
  <img src="topmenubuttons/kunden_OFF.png" mouseover and stuff... />
</a>
```

The second argument to the `link_to` helper is the path, the 3rd is a hash of options that will become the attributes of the `<a>` tag.

If you want both the image and the text to be within the `<a>` tag you do have to concatenate the `image_tag` with the text. Like you attempted to do but, it had a comma in the wrong place. It should be:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("topmenubuttons/kunden_OFF.png" , :mouseover => "topmenubuttons/kunden_OVER.png", :mouseon => "topmenubuttons/kunden_ON.png", :title => "Kunden") + "<span>Customer</span>" , customers_path ) %>
```

I included a `span` around "Customer" so it can be directly styled.

Comment: It prints <span> Customer </span> in the link tag and not just "Customer".

Comment: oops, i forgot to add this: "<span>Customer</span>".html_safe. Or just leave the span out if you want

Answer (score 1):

Let try this:

```
<%= link_to customers_path do %>
  <%= image_tag("topmenubuttons/kunden_OFF.png" , :mouseover => "topmenubuttons/kunden_OVER.png", :mouseon => "topmenubuttons/kunden_ON.png", :title => "Kunden") %>
  <span>Customer</span>
<% end %>
```

This will generate some HTML like:

```
<a href="/customers">
  <img ...>
  <span>Customer</span>
</a>
```